# Why classes that implements IValidatableObject requires reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations when used in another class library?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a class library for entities with reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`. 
I have separate class library for data access without reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

I have a class called '`Customer` that uses `RequiredAttribute` which is part of `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`. The data access library is compiling without error.

I modified the `Customer` class and implement `IValidatableObject`. `IValidatableObject` is also part of `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.
When I compile the data access library it requires a reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`. Why does it need to have a reference to `DataAnnotations` while the `RequiredAttribute` does not?

Comment: Are you sure that the attribute is defined in that assembly?  Note that namespaces don't have a one to one relationship with assemblies, and the namespace itself may be split across multiple assemblies.  You may have a reference to another assembly that contains the attribute, but still within the same namespace.

Comment: There are 2 similar assemblies `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` - refer [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: "Why does it need to have a reference to `DataAnnotations` while the `RequiredAttribute` does not?" => I would say this is a wrong question. The question should be => "Why does `RequiredAttribute` compiles without a reference to `DataAnnotations`"?

May be then you will get the correct response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most custom attributes (including `RequiredAttribute`) don't have any influence on compilation. Whereas the possible *types* for an object (its own type, base classes, and any interfaces) can influence things like method overload selection.

As such, the compiler needs to actually *know* all of those types when compiling an assembly that uses your `Customer` class.